# find array of objects with only matched object in subarray mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get an array of objects with the matching id's and with only sub-array **product_price** object with matching attributes **size and model**?

```
      product_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      service_hourly_price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      product_price: [{
        model:{
          type: String,
          enum:['Euro','Japanese']
        },
        size:{
          type: String,
          enum: ['S','M','L','XL']      
        },
        price:{
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        }
      }],
```

Trying to query like this:

```
ProductSchema.aggregate( [
    {$match: { _id: { 
      $in: _id.map(function(_id){ return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) })
    }}},
    { $match : { product_price : {model : 'Euro' , size: 'S'}}}
    ])
```

how can I achieve result like this:

```
products:{
  _id: new ObjectId("61b3ab3ceba5bc724d754929"),
  product_name: 'Basic Service',
  service_hourly_price: 25,
  product_price: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("61b3ab3ceba5bc724d75492a"),
      size: 'S',
      model: 'Euro',
      price: 100
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61b3aa88eba5bc724d7548fb"),
  product_name: 'Horn',
  service_hourly_price: 5,
  product_price: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("61b3aa88eba5bc724d7548fc"),
      size: 'S',
      model: 'Euro',
      price: 110
    }
  ]
}
```

product_price must contain only one matching object in it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample database documents pls

Comment: and is there a reason for your product_price to be an array? u only have one object in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am uncertain why your product_prize is an array with only one object, you could remove the array there, and thus remove the $unwind in the aggregation, but nontheless this works for you right now:

```js
ProductSchema.aggregate( [
    {$match: { 
      _id: { 
      $in: _id.map(function(_id){ return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) })
    }}}, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$product_price'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'product_price.model': 'Euro', 
      'product_price.size': 'S'
    }
  }
])
```

[Here try it out](https://cmql.org/play/?q=1639352861114)

Here the proof with the mongo Compass:
[image]

Comment: Yeah. In resulted array we have only one object in it. It’s ok to remove the array

Comment: Thanks. it works for me